# iOS ADB tool in application

Tags: android, ios, adb

I'm trying to making a tool that I could use as ADB under an iOS Application.
In Android I've found **AdbConnection** for the basic Protocol framework for ADB things.

But In iOS there's nothing I could find. Any Suggesion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since xcode supported mix compile of c/cpp and objective-c and swift, u could make a lib from adb source code since it was open sourced.

What u should do is making a standalone adb and maybe a Wrapper, So that u could use command such as **adb connect** and other thing.

I've ever doing something like what u wanna do but under different platform .[this is a split of adb from android source code](https://github.com/karfield/adb)  And Remember in that link it adb version too low, maybe you should update it to the latest adb version from android source code :)